# MIssing table row values in Array in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table with an ng-repeat row as displayed below

```
<tr ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="lineItem.selected"/></td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.itemNo" ng-options="x as x.itemCode for x in vm.items" name="ItemCode" style="width: 100%;">
          <option value="0">Select Item</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.itemNo.itemName" required /></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.quantity" required /></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.itemNo.unitPrice" required /></td>
    <td><span ng-model="lineItem.lineTotal">{{getLineTotal(lineItem)}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

I have buttons that adds/remove rows from the table with the following angular function

```
$scope.lineItems = [];
$scope.addNewRow = function (lineItem) {
                $scope.lineItems.push({
                    'itemNo': '',
                    'itemNo.itemName': '',
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'itemNo.unitPrice': ''
                });
            }; //new row adds appropriately
```

Now I intend to send `$scope.lineItems` array to the server for processing but `itemNo.itemName` and `itemNo.unitPrice`in the array do not contain any values despite filling the controls on the client. It seems a simple problem but I'm having a hard time cracking it.

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LyLt2f7x/)

Comment: It would be helpful if there was a working sample of code snippet (ex jsfiddle, stackoverflow inbuild snippet..)

Comment: @elpddev please see my edited question.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/LyLt2f7x/1/

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes. But the problem is I the `itemNo.itemName` and `itemNo.unitPrice` as stated in my question are not taking any values of the controls with the models. I don't know if you understand me?

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha I not sure about the whole code, but doing this `ng-model="lineItem.itemNo.itemName"` when the key in the object is `itemNo.itemName` is unjavascriptly :) Meaning in the angular expression, the parser thinks you are trying to get in `lineItem[itemNo][itemName]` instead of `lineItem['itemNo.itemName']`. Best if not using dot in keys names.

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for your observation. I also thought it could be the problem. But having it under the ng-repeat, how am I supposed to do it for the parser to treat it rightly?

Comment: @elpddev sorry my last comment was for you.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha actually AlonEitan did also came with this answer looking at his jsfiddle now. You could do the same, referencing the key with the strict name lineItem['itemNo.itemName'] in the angular expression. But I still suggest finding another structure and not using dot in a key name.